# MySQL query syntax with update and inner join

Tags: mysql

I have been trying to update 1 table based on a value in another table (and there are corresponding Identifers). I simply cannot work out what the syntax is for this, and believe I may have a mix of MS-SQL and MySQL, though very new to this type of coding so having issues unravelling this one.

I am trying to get this query working in MySQL

```
UPDATE timetable As T
SET T.TrainsArrived = T.TrainsArrived + A.TrainsToday
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT TrainID, TrainsToday
    FROM TrainTracker
) A ON A.TrainID = T.TrainID;
```

The issue that the MySQL console is telling me about is on the word 'INNER' and that it is expecting EOF or ';'

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following syntax, and note that the subquery doesn't seem to even be necessary here:

```sql
UPDATE timetable AS T
INNER JOIN TrainTracker AS TT
    ON TT.TrainID = T.TrainID
SET TrainsArrived = T.TrainsArrived + TT.TrainsToday;
```

Comment: Thanks Tim. This worked perfectly for me. The only addition I had to make to my syntax was adding the word 'ON' after you described the table on the INNER JOIN. Thanks mate!